# Implementing Pagination on Smartphone Using CSS Only (No Javascript/JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

My website uses Javascript to split search results on smartphone. The problem is an error occurs for users who have Javascript disabled. I've searched anywhere on how to implement pagination without Javascript but it yielded no result.

It is possible? What are the alternatives?

Comment: nobody has javascript disabled

Comment: @DavidFregoli That is a faulty assumption. There are very few who disable javascript, but there is certainly more than nobody.

Answer (score -1):

CSS should not be used to alter the behaviour of your website. Cascading stylesheets are intended to change the visual appearance of the content.

If pagination is created with javascript then the natural conclusion is to display all results in a long list for users who have disabled javascript.

It is however uncommon that it is javascript in itself which creates the pagination, it is usually provided by the system or technology on the web-server. And usually when there is a javascript/ajax option for pagination there should also be a fallback solution to a normal html/css pagination.

In short:

- Don't use CSS for pagination.
- Pagination without javascript depends entirely on the server-side technology you are using